# Extending @NotEmpty to accept other classes

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I've been trying to make a custom validator so i can just use the @NotEmpty annotation for specific classes (java.util.Calendar or CommandItem in this case). But i get an exception:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: com.bla.DocumentCommandItem
```

Now, the only thing i can think of as to why it doesn't work is that the @NotEmpty annotation itself declares this:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
```

So there is no direct association to the Validator class. But then how does it validate Strings and Collections?

This is my Validator class:

```
    public class DocumentNotEmptyExtender implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmpty,DocumentCommandItem> {

@Override
public void initialize( NotEmpty annotation ) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid( DocumentCommandItem cmdItem, ConstraintValidatorContext context ) {
    if ( !StringUtils.hasText( cmdItem.getId() ) && (cmdItem.getFilename() == null || cmdItem.getFilename().isEmpty()) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Is this even possible?

(as a side note... I've also received this exception when i was making my own similar annotation, but that one mysteriously disappeared. )

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to register your validator in a constraint mapping file like this:

```
<constraint-mappings
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd">

    <constraint-definition annotation="org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty">
        <validated-by include-existing-validators="true">
            <value>com.foo.NotEmptyValidatorForDocumentCommandItem</value>
        </validated-by>
    </constraint-definition>
</constraint-mappings>
```

This mapping file must be registered in `META-INF/validation.xml`:

```
<validation-config xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">

    <constraint-mapping>/your-mapping.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

You can learn more in the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html) and the Bean Validation [specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#xml-mapping-constraintdefinition).

Comment: I've tried your solution.
The XMLs get loaded but i still get the same error. Something weird is happening though...upon enabling trace information for this package, the following 2 lines showed up 5 times during the tomcat startup:
`[  ] 10:13:35,670 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser  - META-INF/validation.xml found.
[  ] 10:13:35,694 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser  - Trying to open input stream for META-INF/validators.xml.`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is listed above by @Gunnar

It caused a few unexepected things though...

NotEmpty is basically a wrapper for the @NotNull and @Size(min=1) constraints. So there is no actual @NotEmpty implementation.

Making my own @NotEmpty implementation for DocumentCommandItem caused 2 things:

- Validator triggering a NotNull and Size validation (and thus a 'no validator found' for the Size-DocumentCommandItem combo
- More importantly, Size-String validations started to fail because it could not find an implementation for it.

So my final solution for this problem:

Make a @Size implementation for DocumentCommandItem
And
Make a @NotEmpty implementation for String

(and possibly i'll have to make another @NotEmpty for Collections)